# Авторизация на ask.fm

Tags: php, curl, авторизация

Здравствуйте.

Хочу написать скрипт авторизации на ask.fm, но возникла проблема уже на первом шаге. В общем, уже много идентичных проблем было, в связи с чем я бросал работу над этим скриптом, но в этот раз решил написать сюда. Ниже приведу свой скрипт. В ответе говорит, что что-то пошло не так, но я думаю, что это какая-то защита. Я новичок в авторизации на сайтах через php cUrl, поэтому прошу отнестись лояльно к этому вопросу :)

```
<?php
function get($url = null, $data = array(), $cookie = null) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    $headers = array(
        "accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "accept-language:ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4",
        "user-agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.3.2924.87 Safari/537.36"
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);

    if(isset($data)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }

    if(isset($cookie)) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $cookie);
    }

    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    preg_match_all("/Set-Cookie: (.*?);/", $response, $cookie);

    $content = substr($response, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));
    $header = substr($response, 0, curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE));

    return array(
        "content" => $content, 
        "header"  => $header, 
        "cookie"  => implode(";", $cookie[1])
    );
}

$homepage = get("https://ask.fm/");

print_r($homepage);
?>
```

Comment: Можете добавить массив data. Что вы в нем передаете?

Comment: Пока ничего, т.к. хочу спарсить со страницы авторизационный токен.

Comment: а у вас логин и пароль есть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так ([источник](http://community.develstudio.org/showthread.php/11258-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-ask.fm)):

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ask.fm');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/10.00 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.2.0");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cook.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
preg_match('/var AUTH_TOKEN = "([\w\W]+)";/Ui',$html,$matches);
$token = $matches[1];

$post = array(
    'authenticity_token' => $token,
    'login' => 'myUsername',
    'password' => 'myPassword',
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ask.fm/session');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/10.00 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.2.0");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cook.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cook.txt');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Подтолкнуло к решению.

Answer (score 1):

Получить страницу можно вот так:

```
    class Ask {

        private $userAgent ;
        private $login = null;
        private $password = null;
        private $url = null;
        private $responce = null;

        private function utfToWin($text) {
            $text = iconv('UTF-8', 'WINDOWS-1251', $text);
            return $text;
        }

        function __construct($login, $password, $url) {
            $this->userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
            $this->login = $login;
            $this->password = $password;
            $this->url = $url;
        }

        private function curl($url, $post = false) {
            $curl = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'CookFile');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'CookFile');
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->userAgent);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            if ($post) {
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
            }
            $res = curl_exec($curl);

            curl_close($curl);
            return $res;
        }


        function run() {
            $this->responce = $this->utfToWin($this->curl('http://ask.fm'));

            return $this;
        }

        public function  getResponse() {
            return $this->responce;

        }



    }

    $ask = new Ask('login', 'pass', 'http://ask.fm');

    var_dump( $ask->run()->getResponse());
```

Ну а там токен вроде в теге `<meta name="csrf-token" content="P1ZQiHqz3EBcnLCXqYIsvUI+dfjO6gnOAzlpigRgPgooZbzMVakLW5PgmRhRS82c3kKmRLl9AM4P/3xFPmdMYA==" />` находиться.

Comment: благодарю за ответ, но у меня код запустился с ошибкой и ничего не получилось :(

Comment: попробовал у себя у меня выводит главную страницу ask.fm

Comment: какая ошибка?...